# python challenge 3 : print strange output

Tags: python

I'm beginner at python and i play python challenge but stuck at problem#3 
My code work fine but output is strange
[problem](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/equality.html)
string in view source

```
x = 0
small = ''
while (x<len(s)) :
   #take string with length 7 one at a time e.g : 'AKLoKPL' 
  y = s[x : x+7]
  op = ord(y[0])-65
  if (0<=op<=25) : #check if the first char is capital 
     if (0 <= ord(y[1]) - 65  <= 25 and 0<= ord(y[2]) - 65 <=25 ) : 
         if(0 <= ord(y[4])- 65 <=25 ) : #check other side
             if (0 <= ord(y[5]) - 65  <= 25 and 0<= ord(y[6]) - 65 <=25 ) :
                 if (0<= ord(y[3])-97 <= 25) :
                     small += y[3] # add small char  (o to small ) 
 x +=7
print(small)
```

I get this output : `egtdjbjfjhcxjkpntpdufhqfwxhqhqskeffmdiudiujmkinphjzujpbfhmxvvgoudtqfuspuzcashuszom`

what i do wrong ? 
and if i'm right what should i do next ?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?  Could you narrow this down to a question you have about python?

Comment: show how should the right output look

Comment: So you're looking for a word that has a lowercase letter with at least 3 uppercase letters on each side?

Comment: `/*take string with length 7 one at a time e.g : 'AKLoKPL' */` is NOT valid Python syntax. What sorcery is this?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes

Comment: @vZ10 http://wiki.pythonchallenge.com/index.php?title=Level1:Main_Page
should lead you to website link

Comment: @AbdelrhmanFawzy: Your link point to "Permission error"

Comment: @AbdelrhmanFawzy I see - You do not have permission to read this page, for the following reason:
You are not allowed to execute the action you have requested.

Comment: in any case, try RegEx for it

Comment: @Coldspeed I'm sorry when i write the post i write comment as in C i will edit it

Comment: ah you can't see soulation if you don't solve the problem ,  this problem 2 http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html
and output is 
"i hope you didnt translate it by hand. thats what computers are for. 
doing it in by hand is inefficient and that's why this text is so long. 
using string.maketrans() is recommended. now apply on the url."

Answer (score 1):

Use such a regex and remove all those loops '[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}'

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}')
print(re.match(pattern, <your_string>).group())
```

Comment: I don't think that the intended solution for an exercise in programing is to use an already built engine to solve the problem, tho.

Comment: what this code do ? pattern = re.compile('[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}')

Comment: Programming is a process of solving issues using all accessible instruments and don't reinventing the bike

Comment: @AbdelrhmanFawzy that code compile a string to a RegEx pattern object which you can use in the future to match with strings.

Comment: @vZ10 - I completely agree... But there is a difference between an exercise and real-world usage. If there wasn't there wouldn't be thousands of students re-implementing quicksort and bubblesort over and over again.

Comment: @zwer one of the points of the Python challenge is to make you use/consider Python's standard library - and `re` is one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use following pattern to match a lowercase letter surrounded by exactly 3 uppercase letters:

```
(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])'
```

(used [negative look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid matches that surround by more than 3 uppercase letters)

```
>>> pattern = r'(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])'
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'ABCDeFGHI')  # surrounded by 4 uppercase letters
[]
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'ABCDeFGHi')  # surrounded by 4/3 uppercase letters
[]
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'aBCDeFGHi')
['e']
```

---

```
letters = re.findall(r'(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])', given_string)
answer = ''.join(letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def three_upper(s):
    return len(s) == 3 and all(x in string.ascii_uppercase for x in s)

def check(s):
    for i in range(3, len(s)-3):
        if three_upper(s[i-3:i]) and s[i] in string.ascii_lowercase and three_upper(s[i+1:i+4]):
            return True
    return False
```

Here's a non-regex solution. The [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) constants save us from messing around with `ord` which can get confusing

Comment: If you're going to use the constants from `string` then you may as well make them into `set`s first for O(1) lookup instead of O(N) which will save a lot of lookup time. Having said that - why not just use `all(ch.isupper() for ch in s)` in `three_upper()` and `s[i].islower()` in `check()` ?

Comment: Having said "having said that"... `return len(s) == 3 and s.isupper()`...